# Django: safe and unsafe html tag <a> with template-supplied URLs

Tags: django, security, django-templates

Since HTML5 does not care if an attribute is enclosed by double-quotes, I used to skip them for the sake of simplicity. For example, I use:

```
<a href=/someURL/someArgs/>Link to some URL</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="/someURL/someArgs/">Link to some URL</a>
```

However, I happened to read a document written by a security hacker, who indicates that if the URL is supplied by Django templates, there may be security problems. That is,

```
<a href={{ someURL }}>Link to some URL</a>      <!--  Unsafe  -->
<a href="{{ someURL }}">Link to some URL</a>    <!--  Safe  -->
```

Is that true? What kinds of security problems are there?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, both of usages provide a similar way to insert a malicious code. It all depends on whether you always control what's in "someURL" or it's something based on input from your web user.